# How can I get exactly date that has highest Close price each weeks? I use quantmod package in r

Tags: r, quantmod, stock

I am a newbie in R and I tried to get the date that have highest close price. I used function `period.max` in `quantmod` package. Here is my code.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("GE")
period.max(Cl(GE),endpoints(GE,on='weeks'))
```

But the result returned the highest Close price but It's not the correlation date, instead of the last day of weeks.

```
2007-01-05 37.97
2007-01-12 37.92
2007-01-19 38.11
2007-01-26 36.75
2007-01-26 36.75
2007-02-09 36.37
2007-02-16 36.47
```

Could you please give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `split`, `lapply`, `do.call` approach:

```
# helper function to return the maximum row
get.max <- function(x) x[which.max(x),]
# split on weeks, loop over each week and get max, rbind back together
week.max <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(Cl(GE), "weeks"), get.max))
```